# Slow saving of Excel file from server using IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, webforms

The problem here is that upon trying to download an excel file with html markup contents. The system takes a long time to download it. Sometimes the save dialog of IE does not appear immediately upon request for download.

The flow is like this. This is a legacy code so I know it looks dumb.

Client request for generation of excel file -> create excel file on server -> query data from DB -> Populate excel with HTML markups together with data from DB -> Send excel file to client using HTTP

Now here comes the problem.

The issue does not always happen, it is intermittent.

Sometimes the save file dialog of IE does not show. Sometimes it takes 6-10 min before it shows. What is the cause of this.

here is how the file is sent through http.

```
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
 Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
 Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of your excel file, if the size is large, it would take time to generate file and download file, I suggest you zipping your file before send it back client via HTTP.

Comment: the size only ranges from 40kb to 100kb. So I argue that it is not the issue. I am not saying you are wrong because you are definitely right. It's just that what is happening seems abnormal.

Comment: In my suggestion, you should put the generating file process to another thread to make sure that your process would not be disturbed by other processes or main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.Name);
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
 Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
 Response.End();
```